# Using cx_Oracle and rpy2 packages caused python.exe stopped working

Tags: python, rpy2, cx-oracle

My OS is windows 7,python 3.6.
I use python package rpy2 to call an algorithm in R, the R algorithm needs data in oracle database. And I also need other data in oracle,so I try to use cx_Oracle to get it. However, when i import cx_Oracle it's allways cause the problem'python.exe stopped working'. My code is:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import cx_Oracle
robjects.r.source('analysis.R')
Rresults = robjects.r.analysis_function()#cause python.exe stopped working
```

But when i didn't import cx_Oracle the rpy2 could successful call R source and get R results.

BTW:I use ODBC to connect oracle database in R source. And in my opinion, it might be the cx_Oracle influence the connection in R source. I'm not sure whether it causes the problem.

Is their anyone has such problem before? Sorry for my bad English, thanks for helping me!

Comment: Can you get logs with python.exe error ?

Comment: I can't accurate translate the log ,i will try,it's says:

    Error event name: APPCRASH,
    Application name: pythonw.exe,
    Version: 3.6.150.1013,
    Error time stamp: 585d67d0,
    Module name: StackHash_aadf.

Comment: What version of cx_Oracle are you using?

Comment: Version is 5.3 + oci12c. I can get datas by cx_Oracle, but when i import it, the error causes when i call for R function.